# É possível detectar a ação de scroll apenas com animação CSS?

Tags: css

É possível detectar a ação de scroll apenas com animação CSS, sem a utilização de javascript? eu encontrei um exemplo nesse link https://codepen.io/Tont/pen/eDJpb mas não consegui identificar como foi feito apenas com CSS. Alguém poderia me dar uma breve explicação de como isso é possível?

Comment: Acho que descobri, vou fazer um exemplo bem mais simples pra vc entender o macete do pulo do gato

Comment: Fiz uma edição e coloquei o último elemento no final do scroll, mas como comentei fiz na correria, mas o conceito vc pode aplicar de forma mais refinada ai

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como falei é um exemplo infinitamente mais simples, mas o que importa é o conceito. E a ideia principal é usar várias divs com `background-attachment: fixed;` Com isso a div de move, mas o que está no background dela não! Então ao rolar a página vc vai revelando alguns elemento, ou escondendo outro...

Eu deixei uma borda no *container* do Balão apenas para vc ver como ele vai "cortando"... Vc pode ir brincando com esses valores e ir alinhando tudo para aparecer ou sumir, pode usar z-index se for o caso etc. Com tempo e paciência vc consegue algo bem interessante.

**OBS:** O exemplo não está perfeito, e tb tentei otimizar para caber aqui no Snippet do site, não está totalmente responsivo e alinhado, mas da para ter uma ideia :)

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    /* overflow-x: hidden; */
}
.container {
    height: 200vh;
    background-image: url(https://openclipart.org/image/2400px/svg_to_png/5525/shokunin-sky-with-clouds.png);
    background-position: top center;
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
}
.aviao {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url(https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/151241/isolated/preview/920fcdacca2bbe597f6c3af8c6a17c09-striped-hot-air-balloon-icon-by-vexels.png);
    background-size: 150px 150px;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: 1px solid silver;
}
.bird {
    position: absolute;
    top: 150vh;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 80%;
    height: 400px;
    background-image: url(https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-UMN2vmxzE-A/V9XCDY4tLOI/AAAAAAAAANk/h-0MaXnVDfcZCSgBpZHH72-Q2w56S3t_QCLcB/s1600/bird_silhouettes_by_frank_1956-d5lkx3d.png);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: top left 200px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.foo {
position: absolute;
top: 155vh;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 120px;
background-image: url(https://www.goodvinil.pt/6396-home_default/vinil-skyline-de-londres.jpg);
background-position: bottom -70px left;
background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
<div class="aviao"></div>
<div class="bird"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>
```